# Statistical error analysis of vector data

Tags: error, vector

Reaching equilibrium in a Monte Carlo simulation often refers to a state where the system has evolved sufficiently such that its statistical properties no longer change significantly with additional sampling. This is particularly important in simulations used for statistical mechanics and thermodynamics, such as molecular dynamics or Metropolis Monte Carlo, where you want to obtain the average properties of the system at a given temperature or other thermodynamic conditions.

```
# File: r_end_to_end_squared_scalar.dat
# Description: Monte Carlo simulation data representing protein dynamics.
#r-end-squared
15398.447852474459
15907.581694436145
15146.459803846192
13690.330559817616
14581.703711851666
14224.026089792113
14084.006450353565
13580.238453116126
13960.916991568824
14369.807625278698
13980.19145816181
14202.61497898913
...
```

To perform statistical error analysis (computing statistical errors for chunks of data taken from different parts of a simulation) on the scalar data, I followed these steps:

1. Collect Data: Run your Monte Carlo simulation and collect the data of the observable(s) of interest at each step.
2. Divide Data into Chunks: Split your data into several equal-sized chunks. The size of each chunk should be large enough to be representative of the simulation but small enough to allow for multiple chunks to be compared.
3. Compute Mean and Standard Error for Each Chunk: For each chunk, calculate the mean and the standard error of the mean (SEM). The SEM is the standard deviation (SD) of the sample divided by the square root of the number of observations in the chunk.
4. Compare Across Chunks: Analyze the means and SEMs across the chunks. If the simulation has reached equilibrium, the means should be consistent with each other, and the SEMs should be of a similar magnitude.

Now, I need to do the same in the case of vector data.

```
# File: r_end_to_end_distance_vec3.dat
# Description: Monte Carlo simulation data representing protein dynamics.
# r_end-X r_end-Y r_end-Z
30.713 56.601 -106.073
31.413 58.011 -107.497
31.178 54.376 -105.913
28.199 49.573 -102.165
33.765 42.533 -107.854
33.714 45.822 -104.822
31.339 46.162 -104.742
32.223 43.949 -103.007
31.195 45.567 -104.458
26.245 44.850 -108.025
24.671 50.060 -104.238
28.268 46.925 -105.838
...
```

Suppose I want to perform statistical error analysis on this data to check if the simulation has reached equilibrium. What formula can I use to do that?

N.B. I am using [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844295/computing-autocorrelation-of-vectors-with-numpy) to compute vector autocorrelation:

$$C(t,{v}n) = \frac 1{n-t}\sum{i=0}^{n-1-t}\vec v_i\cdot\vec v_{i+t}$$

Comment: Equilibrium for vector data is equivalent to equilibrium for all the components, isn't it?  If not, then please explain what you mean by "equilibrium."

Comment: @whuber, Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks, but that changes nothing: in your view, what more is there to a vector "equilibrium" compared to equilibrium of the components *in this specific instance?*  I can't even guess, because I can imagine many simulations where the concepts are equivalent and I can imagine others where they are not, because of subtle short-lag correlations among the outputs--but I have never seen an instance of the latter.

Comment: @whuber, I am using this formula to compute vector autocorrelation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844295/computing-autocorrelation-of-vectors-with-numpy     therefore, plz, suggest me something on the basis of this.

Comment: Could you explain what that has to do with equilibrium?

Comment: @whuber, *--but I have never seen an instance of the latter.* --- I replied to this part of the comment.